# is there a way to start/stop linux processes with python?

Tags: python, linux

I want to be able to start a process and then be able to kill it afterwards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.
You can also use low-level primitives like `fork()` via the `os` module.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a little python script that starts a process, checks if it is running, waits a while, kills it, waits for it to terminate, then checks again. It uses the 'kill' command. Version 2.6 of python subprocess has a kill function. This was written on 2.5.

```
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "60"], shell=False)
print 'poll =', proc.poll(), '("None" means process not terminated yet)'
time.sleep(3)
subprocess.call(["kill", "-9", "%d" % proc.pid])
proc.wait()
print 'poll =', proc.poll()
```

The timed output shows that it was terminated after about 3 seconds, and not 60 as the call to sleep suggests.

```
$ time python prockill.py 
poll = None ("None" means process not terminated yet)
poll = -9

real    0m3.082s
user    0m0.055s
sys 0m0.029s
```

Comment: you can use `os.kill(..)` to kill the process

Comment: or even `proc.terminate()` or `proc.kill()` since python 2.6

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-management

Answer (score 3):

A simple function that uses subprocess module:

```
def CMD(cmd) :
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         close_fds=False)
    return (p.stdin, p.stdout, p.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

see docs for primitive fork() and modules [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.managers), [multithreading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interact with the sub process at all, I recommend the pexpect module ([link text](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/2.4)). You can send input to the process, receive (or "expect") output in return, and you can close the process (with force=True to send SIGKILL).