# Start and terminate sniffer process from Python

Tags: python, bluetooth, packet-sniffers, hci

To debug Bluetooth communication, I want to start sniffer (hcidump -Xt) and dump the data in a file. On the terminal, I can start this command:

```
hcidump -Xt > myfile.txt
```

Then use Ctrl+C to terminate the same.

I want to achieve this using python script. Something like:

```
#start sniffer 
call(["hcidump","-Xt", ">", "myfile.txt"])

#perform any activity

#Stop the sniffer - hcidump
```

Finally, it should stop the sniffer process and all the logs should be stored in the myfile.txt file.
I tried few things such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378974/is-there-a-way-to-start-stop-linux-processes-with-python). But it is not creating the intended file.

Please advise if there is any way to achieve the what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `">"` for redirection!
Nearly the same as this one [How do I pipe a subprocess call to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856583/how-do-i-pipe-a-subprocess-call-in-python-to-a-text-file)