# Cross-platform python library for reporting and manipulating system services?

Tags: python, service

This is an extension to the question [is there a way to start/stop linux processes with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378974/is-there-a-way-to-start-stop-linux-processes-with-python)

I just came across this piece of code:

```
os.system("/etc/init.d/apache2 " + op)
```

...where `op` is the action to perform on the service.

Obviously this is `init`-specific, perhaps even limited to openrc or some such. It's also going to break really easily.

Is there a python library to manage system services ***using the platform's own service manager***?

It could be as simple as an OS Rosetta, but I imagine it's a little more complex if you include non-POSIX OSs.

As opposed to the other question:

- I don't want the service to be a child process of my python app.  Services themselves should be independently managed as normal.
- We should, if possible, use the Operating System's chosen process manager
- On Linux, this could mean any of openrc, init, supervisord, etc.
- I would like it also to run on Windows and OSX, if possible.

We don't necessarily need complex operations.  Start, stop, restart, reload, and status is ok.

Answer (score 0):

** Interim Answer - POSIX systems only **

Ansible appear to have written a class to do exactly that [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/09aa79c58f93029a87ed3f4c42c8f04631472575/system/service.py#L383%20here), at least for POSIX-derived OSs.

From the code:

> Supported init systems include BSD init, OpenRC, SysV, Solaris SMF, systemd, upstart.

It appears to be a class called "LinuxService" which has a number of functions:

```
get_service_status()
service_enable()
service_control()
```